# Are there languages that allow goto statement to only go down?

Tags: programming-languages, goto

`goto` statements can sometimes be useful to go down (to lower lines of code) in code, but can create a mess if used to go up (to higher lines of code). Therefore, I am wondering if there is any language that only allows `goto` statement to go down, e.g, `godown`.

Edit:

My main motivation for asking this question is this question [Why does Go have a “goto” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064981/why-does-go-have-a-goto-statement)

I feel like if designers of a modern language like `go` decided to use `goto` statement there is a place for it. Also, as pointed out in one of the answers to the question, `goto` are used in `go` source code.

When I said "create a mess", I was referring to something like this, in a more complicated scenario:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    i := 0
back:
    i++
    fmt.Println(i)
    if i < 10 {
        goto back
    }
    fmt.Println("we are finished")
}
```

Comment: "but can create a mess if used to go up" - what do you mean? To higher placed lines of code (I can't see the difference)? Out of a block (then it's the opposite)?

Comment: Are you looking for [goto docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx) from MSDN (on C#)? If so, the answer to your question is a trivial 'yes'.

Comment: Any sufficiently talented developer can create an equally incomprehensible mess with only downward gotos just as easily.

Comment: Most languages allow you to define subroutines in any order you want, or to switch the branches of a conditional around (by negating the condition), so any notion of "up" and "down" is arbitrary anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's interesting to consider how things could be set up so that it's not arbitrary.

Comment: so if I want, for some reason, to change the order I'll get a compile error and will have to refactor the go-down logic? sounds worse than goto tbh :|

Comment: Your "messy" example is actually a pretty neatly structured do-while loop.

Comment: Maybe `throw` or  `raise` exceptions in C++, Java, or Ocaml?

Answer (score 6):

Some languages allow labelled break. This is a break that allows out of the loop of any nesting, like this

```
outer:
   for (var i = 0 ; i < M ; i++) {
       for ( var j = 0 ; j  < N ; j++) {
            if (f[i, j]) {
                break outer; 
            }
        }
    }
```

This can be seen as "goto only down and out", which is a far more restricted version of "goto only down".

Comment: In a similar vein, try/catch is also a veiled and more strictly regulated goto that only goes "down", so to speak.

Comment: @Flater, tom me the ability to go through function call stack, and the "exceptional" semantics make it distinct from "another goto". Although C `setjmp` / `longjmp` is somewhere in the middle between `goto` and exceptions.

Comment: At least in C#, throws and and catches get translated to literal gotos. They're just compiler-managed rather than developer-managed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any [programming] languages that do this; if it's "bad" enough to allow goto *at all* then it will allow a goto to go *anywhere*.
I seem to recall a *scripting* language that only searched forward for the target of a goto statement but, sadly, I can't remember which one; it may have been a [very] early version of DOS.

Comment: JVM bytecode has `GOTO`, but it doesn't allow you to jump to anywhere. You can only a) jump a maximum of about 2 billion bytecode instructions forward or backward, and b) you can only jump to a location within the same method.

Comment: "if it's "bad" enough to allow goto at all then it will allow a goto to go anywhere": Well, no. If you are not allowed to go up you cannot construct any difficult to understand loops (I think this is what the OP meant by the possibility to "create a mess"), you can only skip a few lines in the body of your current function. IMO this kind of goto is not that bad, even though you can use higher level constructs such as `try-catch-finally` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are only few cases that I think an only-go-down `goto` statement might be useful, but all can be done more elegantly via `break` and `switch` statements.

There is no need for `Goto-down` statement, in my opinion, and I'm not aware of any mature or experimental programming language with such an ability.